Django — Не могу вывести записи из модели
У меня есть модель, значения из которой я хочу вывести на странице. Данные в таблице есть, но на странице их почему-то нет.
models.py:
from django.db import models

class Reviews(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True, verbose_name='Имя')
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True, verbose_name='Email')
    text = models.TextField(verbose_name='Отзыв')

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'review'
        verbose_name = 'Отзыв'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Отзывы'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

views.py:
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from goods.models import Products, Reviews

def ShowReview(request):
    reviews = Reviews.objects.all()

    context = {
        'reviews': reviews
    }
    return render(request, context)

HTML:
{% for x in reviews %}
<div class="review-card">
    <p class="review-name">{{ x.name }}</p>
    <p class="review-text">{{ x.text }}</p>
</div>
{% endfor %}

Данные в таблице:

upd: создал template для рендера, из основного HTML-файла вставил в него только это:
{% for x in reviews %}
<div class="review-card">
  <p class="review-name">{{ x.name }}</p>
  <p class="review-text">{{ x.text }}</p>
</div>
{% endfor %}

Изменил одну строчку во views:
return render(request, 'goods/review_template.html', context)

Подключил template в основной HTML-файл через include, но ничего не поменялось
upd2: Попробовал добавить div с текстом в template, и текст отобразился, а цикл с данными из модели - нет. Можно сделать вывод, что проблема не в неправильном подключении template.

добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как задать хороший вопрос

а куда именно вы возвращаете ваш render из view? в какой template?

Сегодня всю ночь промучался с аналогичной проблемой. всевозможные варианты пробовал и костылями и так и через инклуд. если решишь, отпиши пожалуйста. пока ищу решение

шаблон может быть недоступен в случае отсутствия регистрации приложения в settings.py (в таком случае вернет ошибку при переходе на страницу)

в settings.py приложение зарегистрировано

а папка с темплейтами у вас как прописана? что пишет консоль джанго при запуске сервера - теплейт находится или не находится?

при запуске сервера консоль не ругается. При открытии страницы, где подключен этот темплейт, в консоли он не упоминается. Папка с темплейтами прописана без ошибок, другие страницы, находящиеся в ней, открываются без проблем. Если нужны более конкретные данные, то уточните что именно, пожалуйста. Я только начинаю свой путь джангиста и пока не всё понимаю

Нашёл решение своей проблемы:
Во views.py вместо использования отдельной функции ShowReview(), переместил все переменные в основную функцию, которая рендерит страницу product, к которой я подключал шаблон. Цикл for из шаблона перенёс в product.html.
Скорее всего, мне стоило сразу отправить весь код из views.py, а не только одну функцию из него, тогда бы решение, скорее всего, нашлось бы быстрее.
